# Win32 get the HWND of the object which sent the event from the Window WndProc

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm unsure how to get the HWND of the control that sent the event from the WndProc of the parent Window. The reason I need the HWND is because some metadata about the control is stored in one of its user-defined slots (information about wrapper function pointers, and such) however after some fiddling it seems I need to filter and dispatch events from the parent window.

ie: the user clicks a button, but the event is sent to WM_COMMAND of the buttons parent Window. How can I get the HWND of the button from here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [WM_COMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages send from child controls the child `HWND` is sent in `lParam`.

Comment: [WM_NOTIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx) does something similar.  The `lParam` is a pointer to an `NMHDR`, which has an `hwndFrom` member.